# Spring XD container groups

Tags: containers, spring-xd

I have put the containers into three groups (group1,group2,group3) is it possible to deploy a stream to group1 as a priority and then, if all containers in group1 are down, to group2 as second perference and avoid going to group3.

e.g. module.*.criteria=groups.contains('group1','group2')"

this is for springXD 1.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at this time; the container match is static against container properties.

We have talked about exposing more flexibility for container matching and it will be considered in a future release.

Feel free to open a [JIRA new feature issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD).

That said, could you explain your requirement in more detail? For example if group1 has 1 container and group2 has 3, the deployment topology of your stream(s) would be very different depending on whether group1's container is running or not.